# Progress of encryption thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, encryption, file-io, progress-bar

I am writing a simple program to take a file, encrypt it with AES, and store the output in a separate file using Java. Java is a new language for me, but it's similar to C# in some ways and I've been using C# for a while so the learning as been going relatively smoothly.

My question is that I would like to run the AES cipher in a separate thread, which seems easy enough, but I would like to be able to report an approximate progress to the user in a Swing progress bar. I don't know how to get a status of the encryption to be able to report that back to the user.

I did have an idea, and I wanted to get input on that unless there is a significantly easier way to do it. My idea was to, before the encryption starts, get a size of the input file in bytes, then, on a timer, find the number of bytes that are currently in the output file to determine the percentage complete. However, I do wonder if I'll be able to open a new file handle on the output file when I will have an open handle in another thread in Java. Is my solution possible or is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: what package you are using for AES ?

Comment: Haven't yet decided that. If there's one that makes this easier, I'll use that. I had been reading into javax.crypto.cipher and that seemed promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here should be the approach -

strToEncrypt = the file content (lets suppose)
  You should use the `cipher.getOutputSize(strToEncrypt.getBytes().length)`

to get output estimate of the file. Now this is tricky - and you should run some sample codes to determine the file size when some number of bytes are written. `Windows can give a different estimate of file size` whereas `UNIX will give your the correct file size (in terms of byte length you get from this code)`

Once you get the estimate of the byte array size - you can use `java.io.File` to get the size and calculate the % out of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size of the file, use something like [CountingInputStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/CountingInputStream.html) and compute the percentage using the bytes read so far with `getCount()`.